Ubuntu 24.04 fresh install - Left channel coming out both speakers, no right channel
Title. Dell Optiplex 3040M.
In sound settings if you click Test then Left speaker the sound comes out the center - i.e. both speakers. Right does not play at all - though the GUI meter shows that it thinks it's playing sound.
Headphone socket is correct, only HDMI is the problem, have confirmed it's not the TV itself by plugging my laptop into it via the same cable.
The fact that the left is coming out of both suggests some kind of internal mapping problem.
Ran pavucontrol and the sound card selection is correct, tried swapping to prosound and back, but it didn't help
Ran alsamixer, and I have no idea what I'm doing with that so gave up.
Edit: sudo dmesg : https://pastebin.com/dj00MeeL
Edit 2: wpctl status: https://pastebin.com/TrHRtvtL
$ wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, cookie:1533949863]
 └─ Clients:
        32. pipewire                            [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1238]
        34. WirePlumber                         [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1237]
        35. WirePlumber [export]                [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1237]
        47. GNOME Settings                      [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:13005]
        50. gnome-shell                         [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1422]
        51. GNOME Shell Volume Control          [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1422]
        52. GNOME Volume Control Media Keys     [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1583]
        53. xdg-desktop-portal                  [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:2047]
        54. speech-dispatcher-dummy             [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:3208]
        59. Firefox                             [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:13055]
        98. wpctl                               [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:14568]
        99. Mutter                              [1.0.5, telly@dellbuoy, pid:1422]
 
Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      42. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *  118. Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI) [vol: 0.85]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   96. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:
        55. speech-dispatcher-dummy                                     
             57. output_FL       > HDMI 0 *:playback_FL [init]
             66. output_FR       > HDMI 0 *:playback_FR [init]
       156. GNOME Settings                                              
             44. input_FL        < ALC3234 Analog:capture_FL    [active]
            164. monitor_FL     
            165. input_FR        < ALC3234 Analog:capture_FR    [active]
            166. monitor_FR     
       170. GNOME Settings                                              
            152. monitor_FR     
            159. input_FL        < HDMI 0 *:monitor_FL  [active]
            168. monitor_FL     
            169. input_FR        < HDMI 0 *:monitor_FR  [active]
 
Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:
 
Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.pro-output-0
         1. Audio/Source  alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.pro-input-0
 
$ wpctl inspect 118
id 118, type PipeWire:Interface:Node
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0255,102806bb,00100002 HDA:80862809,80860101,00100000"
    alsa.device = "3"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    alsa.id = "PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7220000 irq 129"
    alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3234"
    alsa.name = "HDMI 0 *"
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7220000 irq 129"
    api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    api.alsa.headroom = "0"
    api.alsa.path = "hdmi:0"
    api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
    api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
    api.alsa.period-num = "32"
    api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
    audio.adapt.follower = ""
    audio.channels = "2"
    audio.position = "FL,FR"
    card.profile.device = "8"
  * client.id = "35"
    clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
  * device.id = "42"
    device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
    device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
    device.routes = "1"
  * factory.id = "18"
    factory.mode = "merge"
    factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
    library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
  * media.class = "Audio/Sink"
  * node.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
    node.driver = "true"
    node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
  * node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo.3"
  * node.nick = "HDMI 0 *"
    node.pause-on-idle = "false"
  * object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hdmi:0:playback"
  * object.serial = "558"
  * priority.driver = "696"
  * priority.session = "696"

